# Change URL of custom post type and form dynamically based on values of custom fields

Tags: wordpress, url, custom-post-type

I was looking for a solution to create custom URL for a custom post type based on the values from custom fields. I have created a CPT named Quiz, the Add New Section have some custom fields to select. Now I wanted to change URL and title of this post as per the values I get from custom fields.

I am using ACF Pro to create custom fields.

Code through this I could do so - ( may help others too )

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'update_title', 10, 3 );

function update_title($post_id, $post, $update ){
global $wpdb;
if($post->post_type == 'post_type'){
$value1 = get_post_meta($post_id,'meta_key_name',  true);
$value2 = get_post_meta($post_id,'meta_key_name', true);
$batch_number = get_post_meta($post_id,'batch_number', true);
$day = get_post_meta($post_id,'day', true);
$title = $value1."-".$value2."-Batch-".$batch_number."-Day-".$day;
$name_query = "UPDATE `wp_posts` SET `post_title` = '".strtoupper($title)."' , post_name='".strtolower($title)."' WHERE `ID` = ".$post_id;
$wpdb->query($name_query);
}
```

Comment: I have solved this problem by adding custom filed values in functions.php and run an update query to update title and post_name and it worked like charm. Used add_action('save_post', function_name, 10,3); to run this.

Comment: I would like suggest you to use CMB2 instead of which you are using. It will be more helpful to you in every aspect of custom fields.